# Remove some series from query in influx

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have query:

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative(max("value"), 10s)
                   FROM "interface_rx" 
                   WHERE "host" =~ /host.+/
                             AND "instance" =~ /eth.+/ 
                             AND "type" = 'if_octets' 
                             AND $timeFilter
                   GROUP BY time(5m), "instance"
                   fill(null)
```

It returns all found series - and this is too much.

I want to cut down sequences with values of non_negative_derivative(max("value"), 10s) > 100.

If I do this:

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative(max("value"), 10s) 
      as irx 
      FROM "interface_rx" 
      WHERE "host" =~ /host.+/ 
            AND "instance" =~ /eth.+/ 
            AND "type" = 'if_octets'
            AND $timeFilter 
            AND irx > 100
     GROUP BY time(5m), "instance" 
     fill(null)
```

influx just ignores me (empty results).

How can I filter out slow series from result? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to refer to `irx` inside the body of the query.

To achieve the result you're looking for you'll need to issue two queries:

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative(max("value"), 10s) AS irx
               INTO tmp
               FROM "interface_rx" 
               WHERE "host" =~ /host.+/
                         AND "instance" =~ /eth.+/ 
                         AND "type" = 'if_octets' 
                         AND $timeFilter
               GROUP BY time(5m), "instance"
               fill(null)
```

and

```
SELECT irx FROM tmp WHERE irx > 100 GROUP BY instance
```